# Python 'iso-8859-1' encoding resulting in unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, iso-8859-1

We are translating German to English with custom dictionary for which text file data is converted into dictionary type.
Some of the German words are resulting in unexpected words when read.

Text File

```
Großhandelsverkaufspreise=Wholesale prices
Überlassung=Transfer
Vierteljährliche=Quarterly
```

```
f = open("dictionary.txt", "r", encoding="iso-8859-1")
replacements = {}
for line in f:
    arr = line.strip().split("=")
    if len(arr) == 2:
        k = arr[0]
        v = arr[1]
        replacements[k.strip()] = v.strip()
print(replacements)
```

Incorrect Output:
{'GroÃ\x83Å¸handelsverkaufspreise': 'Wholesale prices'}

Comment: It appears the file isn't iso-8859-1 encoded. When I specifically write that text in iso-8859-1, your program works for me.

Comment: You could post the first line of the file in bytes so we can play with encodings: `print(open("dictionary.txt", "rb").readline()))`.

Comment: @tdelaney probably already explained what's wrong; if you still need help. please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors -- in particular, we need to see the actual bytes of -- say -- the first line of the file. Looks like it's probably `b"Gro\xc3\x9f"` which is UTF-8.

Comment: `'Großhandel'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')` gives `'GroÃ\x83Å¸handel'` so it looks like _double_ [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: Thanks Everyone ..File I was reading was in UTF-8 format hence was getting unusual  data. Changed the code to create the text file with iso-8859-1 encoding .Its working fine now .

Comment: Probably more sensible going forward to try to use UTF-8; see also  https://utf8everywhere.org/